# Converting a federated authentication token from a remote system to a custom token created with Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-security

We are using Spring Authorization Server 0.3.1 successfully in production.

I want to integrate the federated identity sample that can be found on Github here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver

We did so successfully. The last part to this puzzle is distributing normalized tokens. By that I mean, we have custom tokens for our Spring Authorization Server solution with custom claims. We want to convert the incoming federated token [from Google, FB etc] to our custom token.

There are some documentation on the Interwebz around this here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10033

The goal is to take any remote federated token and convert it to a custom locally generated Spring Authorization Server token with extra claims that get added through our customizer and then return that to our Single Paged Application user. The SPAs require the extra claims to operate.

Also, the SPA will try to refresh the token with SAS or the federated identity provider. It will fail with the remote system as the redirect URIs have not been set up remotely.

Flow:

- User logs in from SPA 1
- User is redirected to SAS instance
- User chooses to log in with Google's federated identity provider
- User authenticates with Google
- User comes back to SAS instance with a valid token
- If user doesn't yet exist in the system, we save a new user record
- Token gets converted to our own type of token
- User is redirected back to SPA 1
- SPA 1 talks to SAS server to retrieve the newly created token
- Life goes on and life is good ‍♂️

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is a broad question. Could you provide information on what you've done so far and where you keep getting stuck?

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg - Thanks for getting in touch so fast. I've seen your name all over the SAS codebase so appreciate your reply. I've updated the question to hopefully make it more understandable.

Comment: Sure thing. Apologies, I'm still not understanding where exactly you're getting stuck. Are you basically asking how to add extra claims to the token that comes back to your SPA? See [OAuth2TokenCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer). Or is it something else? I don't understand the part about the SPA talking to identity provider. Why would it do that?

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg. I think we are looking at mainly one issue as you pointed out. 1. An incoming federated token is missing claims / scopes etc. that need to be added. A "nice-to-have", and why I mentioned normalizing the token is to have email be the "principal" for example.

Comment: The existing federated sample demonstrates how to configure a claim as the principal name for both GitHub and Google as examples. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/3f5e7c793bbc9875d2753fb5427423d553dd9b16/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/resources/application.yml#L21-L25).

Comment: It also demonstrates how to customize claims of a token. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/3f5e7c793bbc9875d2753fb5427423d553dd9b16/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/security/FederatedIdentityIdTokenCustomizer.java#L60). You can customize not just the `id_token` as in that example, but also the `access_token`.

Comment: Will try this out today and report back.

Answer (score 0):

As @steveriesenberg pointed out in the comments, [the federated security examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/3f5e7c793bbc9875d2753fb5427423d553dd9b16/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver) already show how adding and removing claims can be accomplished with the customizer as well as normalizing the principal name.

[How to customize claims.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/3f5e7c793bbc9875d2753fb5427423d553dd9b16/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/security/FederatedIdentityIdTokenCustomizer.java#L60)

[How to normalize principal name](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/3f5e7c793bbc9875d2753fb5427423d553dd9b16/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/resources/application.yml#L21-L25)

Thank you Steve!